# how can I search in 2 different arrays of objects if there is an id withn both when doing a map?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am developing an app in React using redux, I set the reports (which is an array of objects), and the properties (another array of objects) both to the store. Then I do a `properties.map(property =>(...more code))` but every time a property is created I need to check if the `property.id_property` is also in the `reports.id_property`. I have been trying to include a loop inside the `property.id_property` but it does not work

This is the properties map:

```
{properties.map(property => (
   <div id="propertiesList"
        key={property.id_property}
        className="card  my-2 ml-2 mainProperty"
        style={{
            maxWidth: "14rem",
            maxHeight: "12rem",
            cursor: "pointer"
         }}
         onClick={() => this.showPropertyDetails(property.id_property)}>
      {property.photo_property === null || property.photo_property == "null" 
          ? (
              <img style={{ height: 100 }}
                   src="https://www.esididiomas.es/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/casa.jpg"
                   className="card-img-top"
                   alt="...">
          ) : (
              <img style={{ height: 100 }}
                   src={`${host}properties/${property.photo_property}`}
                   className="card-img-top"
                   alt="..."/>
          )}
       <div style={{backgroundColor: "rgb(70, 88, 102)", color: "white", textAlign: "center"}}
            className="card-header card-bottomPart">
           <div className="card-body">
               <p style={{ fontSize: 14 }} className="card-title" {property.address_line1}</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returns a boolean:

```
reports.some(item => item.id_property === property.id_property)
```

or if you need to return a value:

```
reports.find(item => item.id_property === property.id_property)
```

Comment: are you trying to filter before you map the rendered items?